# How to avoid circular dependency: customer / user / expense / job_order

Tags: sql, circular-dependency

I have the following relationships:

- 1 `customer` has 1 or more `users`
- 1 `customer` has 1 or more `job_orders`
- 1 `user` has 1 or more `expenses`
- 1 `job_order` has 1 or more `expenses` (since 1 `expense` may have a linked `job_order`)

Usually, I would have accepted such a structure (since the check can be handled by a higher layer of software) but now I'm not sure anymore... Is it possible to normalize and remove the above circular dependency?

Comment: Hi - why do you think the structure is not normalized and has a circular dependency? It looks fine to me

Comment: Because one user's expence could be linked to a job order that doesn't belong to to the user's customer